# The function of validate input params

Tags: kdb

Definded the method to validate input params :

```
`validate_paramaters{[Date;Code;CodeType;Param]
 if[ not (14h=abs[type[Date]]);
      [
           .log.info["\tError - Exiting function - Date is not of the correct type"];
           : `$"Error - Date is not of the correct type"
         ]
       ];
if[ not (11h=abs[type[Code]]);
         [
           .log.info["\tError - Exiting function - Code is not of the correct type"];
           : `$"Error - Code is not of the correct type"
         ]
       ];
if[ not (-11h=type[CodeType]);
         [
           .log.info["\tError - Exiting function - CodeType is not of the correct type"];
           : $"Error - CodeType is not of the correct type"
         ]
       ];
:`validated

}`
```

But now The CodeType`s type add more addition :

```
 -11h=type[CodeType] `also can be` 99h=type[CodeType]
```

Please give me a guidance how can i validate the CodeType now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `not (-11h=type[CodeType])` with `not any -11 99h in type CodeType`

The keyword `in` allows you to compare the type of CodeType with a *list* of numeric types. This returns a boolean list. For example:

```
q)CodeType:`sample`dictionary!`a`b
q)-11 99h in type CodeType
01b
```

The `any` prepended to that returns a `1b` if ANY members of the list are True.

```
q)any -11 99h in type CodeType
1b
```

Finally, you seem to be throwing errors if the CodeType is NOT one of the aforementioned types, so we'll prepend this all with a `not`.

Comment: Might be a little cleaner to do `not type[CodeType] in -11 99h`. Easier to read and doesn't require the use of `any`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to Jemma's response, you could also try a more concise method:

```
validate:{[d;names;types]
  if[count fails:key[d] where not any each types=type each d[names];
  :"error - exiting - ",("," sv string fails)," are not of correct type"];
 };
```

This first parameter of this function is a dictionary (`d`) where the key is the names of the arguments and the values are their corresponding values. This argument can be passed along with the names of the variables you are querying and the types they should be. Nested lists should be used if you're looking for multiple types to conform against.

For example, here is a dictionary with valid entries.

```
q)d:`date`code`codetype!(.z.d;`some`code`to`test;`thetypeofmycode)
q)validate[d;`date`code`codetype;(-14;11;(-11 99h))]
q)
```

However, you can see this returns an error if the dictionary is updated with an invalid datatype.

```
q)d[`code]:"wrongtype"
q)d[`date]:.z.p
q)validate[d;`date`code`codetype;(-14;11;(-11 99h))]
"error - exiting - date,code are not of correct type"
```

Just note that the list of types has to be in the same order as the dictionary

To incorporate your .log.info you can adapt the above function as so:

```
validate:{[d;names;types]if[count fails:key[d] where not any each types=type each d key d;
  .lg.info"error - exiting - ",("," sv string[fails])," are not of correct type";
  :"error: ",("," sv string[fails])," - type incorrect"]}
```

Referring to the example above, this would return the same result but this time logging the error using .log.info also.